# Trying to map a 2 D hexagonal lattice point for convex hull study

Tags: matlab, mathematical-lattices

I am trying to map a 2 D hexagonal lattice point for convex hull study. But I can only get rectangular lattice. Here is the code:

Map a hexagonal lattice on a 2D plane

```
u = 0:1:100;
if mod(u,2) == 0;
  v = 0:2*sqrt(3):50*sqrt(3);
else 
  v = 1:2*sqrt(3):50*sqrt(3)    
end
```

Define the area in which the convex hull should be constructed. Send all the data points to the convhull function.

```
[u,v] = meshgrid(u,v);
idx = sqrt((u-25).^2+(v-25).^2) <= 25 ;
u = u(idx);
v = v(idx);
c = convhull(u,v);
```

Plot the image

```
plot(u(c),v(c),'r-',u,v,'b.');
hold off
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statement doesn't work like this in MATLAB. The program will always only follow one path through, not different paths for each vector element as you seem to think.

Instead, use logical indexing:

```
u = 0:1:100;
index = mod(u,2) == 0;
v(index) = 0:2*sqrt(3):50*sqrt(3); 
v(~index) = 1:2*sqrt(3):50*sqrt(3);
```

(Not tested could fail if vector sizes here don't match).

However, this still doesn't get you a hexagonal grid, because the `meshgrid` function generates a rectangular grid by definition.

An hexagonal grid is two rectangular grids intertwined. One approach to generate it could be as follows:

```
u = 0:1:100;
v = 0:2*sqrt(3):50*sqrt(3); 
[v,u] = meshgrid(v,u);
v(2:2:end,:) = v(2:2:end,:)+sqrt(3);

% and then the rest of your code:
idx = sqrt((u-25).^2+(v-25).^2) <= 25;
u = u(idx);
v = v(idx);
c = convhull(u,v);
plot(u(c),v(c),'r-',u,v,'b.');
axis equal
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thank you very much. The logic is a lot clearer to me now.